# Volume of Plasma as Compared To Gasses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

When a material turns from gas to plasma state, does the volume increase, or does it remain the same? And if it does increase, does it depend on temperature and pressure?

Comment: Do you mean molar volume?  If so, I am not sure there's a simple comparison because plasmas tend not to be in equilibrium so thermodynamic comparisons become tricky.

Comment: I was just thinking about volume in general of the material changing, with mass at a constant. Say about 6g of substance X as a gas occupies 6cm^3. If substance X were to be converted to plasma, would it increase in volume for the same amount of mass?

Comment: In the simplest scenario I can imagine, we assume an ideal, monatomic gas (e.g., hydrogen) is heated enough to liberate the electrons from each nuclei to form a plasma (technically, hydrogen is not an ideal gas but this is hand wavy).  If we keep assuming that the plasma remains an ideal gas and we confine the volume, then the pressure will have to increase as the temperature has increased greatly.